# How to iterate Select and add index without AsEnumerable/Select((q, index))

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6, .net-4.6.1

I take a list of records from DB, which I need to paginate later, but filter before. Somethings like this:

```
... // I'm inside another .Select()
    PaymentsReceived = p.ActivityPayments.Select(q => new
    {
        Description = q.PaymentTypeID == (int)PaymentType.ACCONTO ? labelAcconto : q.PaymentTypeID == (int)PaymentType.SINGOLOPAGAMENTO && p.PaymentMethod.ID == 1 ? labelRata : labelImporto,
        Amount = q.Amount,
        Date = q.Date,
        Paid = q.Paid
    }).Select(q => new
    {
        Description = q.Description,
        Amount = q.Amount,
        Date = q.Date,
        Paid = q.Paid,
        Visible = (Month1 == null || (q.Date.HasValue && q.Date.Value.Month >= Month1)) &&
         (Month2 == null || (q.Date.HasValue && q.Date.Value.Month <= Month2)) &&
         (Year1 == null || (q.Date.HasValue && q.Date.Value.Year >= Year1)) &&
         (Year2 == null || (q.Date.HasValue && q.Date.Value.Year <= Year2)) &&
         (InitialPayment != true || (q.Description == "Rata #1")) // here's I valutate indexing
    })
}).Where(p => p.PaymentsReceived.Any(q => q.Paid && q.Visible));
```

What I need is, on `q.Description`, add a `+ "#" + index` where `q.Description == "Rata"`, which goes from 0 to N (`ActivityPayments` its already ordered).

So a list of Description should be:

```
Importo
Fatturazione
Rata #1
Importo
Rata #2
Rata #3
```

And so on.

Can't use `ToList` and/or `AsEnumerable` (since it will download in memory such 1 million records), so I need to exclude the `Select((q, index))`.

Can't neither first paginate, than go `ToList` (because the filtering depends by the values of these records, looks at `== "Rata #1"`), so I need to filtrate due to `index` before paginate.

Are there any solution to this?

Comment: What ORM (and what version) and database are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron added as tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want is `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Description ORDER BY q.PaymentTypeID) as ROW` in SQL, but to my knowledge this isn't supported in any version of EF yet. A complicated GroupBy might get you there, but it still wouldn't count up like you're wanting. The only way I know how to tackle that is by exposing the description at the pagination level. I suppose if you wrote a raw sql query you could get there.